# Java regex: replace a substring that is preceded by '$'

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to know if there is a proper way to replace a substring that is preceded by `$`. For instance, if we have strings that look like:

`String s = "something variable = $firstname something something";` or

`String s = "something foo($firstname) something else";`

I would like to replace all occurences of a "variable"(i.e is preceded by `$`), in this case, `$firstname` with `'x'` (including the single quotes). So we should end up with the result:

`String s = "something variable = 'x' something something";` or

`String s = "something foo('x') something else";`

But I'm not sure how to write a proper regex that can do this.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid SQL Injection by wrapping values in quotes? If yes then take a look at [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). If that is not the case then still your question can be [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) so consider adding some context about what you want to achieve.

Comment: I didn't include a greater context because it would just clutter the essence of my problem. I'm dealing with a pretty niche, custom problem where binding variables are strings of alphanumeric characters that are preceded with $. But because I don't have access to the actual value of the binding variables, I simply want to replace them with some placeholder value in order to simulate that it has a value. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I'm not sure that this information helps in coming up with the regex.

Answer (score 1):

try something like `\$[a-zA-Z]+`

$ followed by one or more characters in a-z,A-Z

```
String s = "something variable = $firstname something something";
```

matches `$firstname`

```
String s = s.replaceAll("<your regex>", "'x'");
```

Comment: Thank you this almost works. I think the regex needs some extra escapes like this: `String s = s.replaceAll("(\\$\\S+)", "'x'");`

Comment: This actually doesn't work with my second example, as it will also delete the closing parenthesis. So `String s = "something foo($firstname) something else";` becomes `String s = "something foo('x' something else";`

Comment: then try \$[a-zA-Z]+

Comment: Yes thank you that works! I.e: `String s = s.replaceAll("\\$[a-zA-Z]+", "'x'");`